# 500 Error While Connecting MongoDB Connection in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mongodb

Checked in php info file as well and mongo is enable there

So, how can i fix this error ?

Here is my code

```
<?php
   // echo phpinfo();
   // exit;

   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();

   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;

   echo "Database mydb selected";

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Yes @vivek_23 , PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /var/www/html/MongoDB/index.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/MongoDB/index.php on line 5

Comment: Does those files have namespaces declared in them? Have you required the autoloader?

Comment: No Not decalared any namspaces

Comment: Add code only which i have added in question